# Can't purge libapache2-mod-php5, corrupt registry

Tags: 13.04, php

I can't purge libapache2-mod-php5. Give me this error.

```
ucfr: Corrupt registry: Duplicate entries for /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
libapache2-mod-php5      /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
libapache2-mod-php5      /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

The folder /etc/php5/ doesn't exists.

Comment: You could try the answer given for [this question, it might fix your issue aswell.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323678/repair-broken-symlinks-reinstall-php5)

Comment: @AndersF.U.Kiær Thanks but doesn't work

Comment: Getting the same error when you try it?

Answer (score 7):

I got same error. I was able to purge all apache and php stuff, but can't install libapache2-mod-php5 back. Gives me same error:

```
Creating config file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini with new version
ucfr: Corrupt registry: Duplicate entries for /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
libapache2-mod-php5      /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
libapache2-mod-php5      /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
libapache2-mod-php5      /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
dpkg: error processing libapache2-mod-php5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-php5
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I did to solve this, was:

```
$ sudo nano /var/lib/ucf/registry
```

and remove duplicated php.ini lines from that file. Not sure, was it pretty thing to do, but it helps.

Comment: f you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: Well it's not. But yeah, I should add this as comment to question, sorry for that. But is is same issue, I wasn't able to purge normally. So I changed my topic and added an solution also